# How do I hide a pop-over while scrolling up or down in ag-grid?

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

There's a column for pop-over and it is present in each cell when I click on it I get the pop-over and choose whatever option I want to choose however when I scroll up or down in the grid the pop-over scrolls with it and goes out of the grid till the top of the screen.
Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: do you have a stackblitz to share?

Comment: Nope, sorry but I can answer any question you have

Comment: Are you mentioning about this popover? [Popover Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-popup-blog-twelmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) You want the popover to maintain position while scrolling?

Comment: Yes, see in this example also when I scroll, the popover is going out of the grid